# Bringing up ethernet device under Debian riscv64

Tags: debian, dhcp, ifupdown

I have a [Sipeed RV 86](https://linux-sunxi.org/Sipeed_Lichee_RV) device, which is a RISCV 64bit. On this,I run a minimal Debian OS, that let's me log in via the USB interface, as the device shows up as `ttyUSB0` on the host Linux PC.

When I then try to bring up networking, I stumble on this error:

```
# ifconfig 
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1630  bytes 89377 (87.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1630  bytes 89377 (87.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e2:95:8c:23:89:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

# ifup usb0
ifup: unknown interface usb0
```

After making the interface known in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/usb0` using:

```
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet dhcp
```

...I get:

```
# ifup usb0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/usb0/e2:95:8c:23:89:85
Sending on   LPF/usb0/e2:95:8c:23:89:85
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on usb0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPDISCOVER on usb0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on usb0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
DHCPDISCOVER on usb0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on usb0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on usb0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
root@licheerv:/etc/network/interfaces.d#
```

I know that my DHCP server is running, and working, as other clients work fine. I also see the network LED on the device blink, so there is activity.

How can I get networking going on this device?

## UPDATE 1

During boot, I also see this:

```
[    **] A start job is running for Raise network interfaces (27s / 5min 15s)
[   33.761420] ldob: disabling
```

## UPDATE 2

Unfortunately, the TPLINK dhcp server logging is severely lacking... it doesn't display much, other than:

[image]

Comment: Your DHCP server may be "working", but it's not assigning you an IP address. Does your DCHP server see the `DHCPDISCOVER` request?

Comment: You can configure the host Linux PC to be an Ethernet bridge between the router and the Sipeed. This can't work if the host Linux PC uses Wifi instead of (wired) Ethernet for its connection to the router. There are other methods available with other drawbacks.